# Menu lateral en la actividad de mapa en android studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio; donde inicia con el mapa como principal. Y este tenga un menu lateral y al seleccionar una de las opciones de dicho menu; muestre un marcador en el mapa. No he podido dar con el código aún. Pero, si pidieran echarme una mano, se los agradecería.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow , te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) , también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Tu pregunta es muy corta y de baja calidad.

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado imprecisa, pero ¿no te valdría con el estándar de la propia documentación? https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer?hl=es-419